# Making throwing exceptions work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've been trying to write a small program with these instructions:

> In this assignment you should write a simple web application with one link on the front page of the web. If the link is clicked, the user will simply be routed to the front page again (using `RedirectToAction`). However, occasionally, the action method might throw an exception (but not always). Occasionally (one in every 5 occasions) the method should throw an `ArgumentException`, and occasionally (again, in maybe 1 in a 5), it should throw a custom Exception object you should declare yourself, called MyApplicationException.

In **HomeController** I have:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    List<Logger> m_loggers = new List<Logger>();

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext fc)
    {
        base.OnException(fc);
        Exception ex = fc.Exception;

        Logger.Instance.Log(ex);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string strLogFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"];
        string strEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"];

        try
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");

            using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.To.Add(strEmail);
                message.Subject = "Villuskilaboð";
                message.Body = "Upp hefur komið villa frá Skilaverkefni 4!";

                using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand = r.Next(1000);

            if(rand % 5 == 0)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Randon villuskilaboð handa þér!");
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message +
                            Environment.NewLine +
                            ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

`Logger` class:

```
public class Logger
{
    List<LogMedia>m_loggers = new List<LogMedia>();

    private static Logger theInstance = null;

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (theInstance == null)
            {
                theInstance = new Logger();
            }
            return theInstance;
        }
    }

    private Logger()
    {
        m_loggers = new List<LogMedia>();
        //m_loggers.Add(new TextFileLogMedia { });
        //m_loggers.Add(new EmailLogMedia { });
    }

   public void Log(Exception ex)
   {
       foreach(LogMedia log in m_loggers)
       {
           log.LogMessage(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
       }
    }
}
```

`LogMedia`

```
public class LogMedia
{
    public virtual void LogMessage(string Message)
    {
    }

    public class OutputWindowLogMedia: LogMedia
    {
        public override void LogMessage(string Message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Message);
        }
    }

    public class TextFileLogMedia: LogMedia
    {
        public override void LogMessage(string Message)
        {
            //File.AppendAllText("c:\\Temp.Log.txt", Message);
        }
    }

    public class EmailLogMedia: LogMedia
    {
        public override void LogMessage(string Message)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I´m stuck for now and seems not getting it to work, my Visual Studio crash and I get error up, don't think that is the exception, I´m so new to it so maybe it´s the box that should come up :)  But the email never get to my account.

What am I still missing to make everything work?  I know the file-thing isn't in this code, trying to make the other things to work first.

I've added information about my eMail in `web.config`.

Comment: Have you stepped through it in the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: I get this error when I go through debugger:
ArgumentException was unhandled by user code and points to the line:
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + Envoriment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);

Comment: That's 99% positive to be due to the if statement above it throwing a new Exception. You need to have a new try/catch around any new Exceptions thrown because the catch that it is in will not try to catch any new Exceptions inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to rework your `Index()` method. <s>I'm not in front of my computer with Visual Studio, but I'm surprised you code gets past the first line in your `try`. Having the `RedirectToAction("Index")` should throw a warning that the rest of the method will never be reached, and create an infinite loop when you try to access the method.</s> The RedirectToAction("Index")` you have in your code does nothing as you don't return the results of that. **Thank you Erik Noren**

This would be how I'd structure your method instead:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    // No need to go higher, as it's always just as random with a modulo
    int rnd = (new Random()).Next(5); 

    try {
        switch (rnd) {
            case 1: // Or any of the 5 numbers you want.
                throw new ArgumentException();
            case 4: // Again, any of the 5 numbers
                throw new MyApplicationException();
            default:
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Do your error logging here.
    }
}
```

Comment: The RedirectToAction is a method call. Since they aren't returning on that line, the response is just throw away. It's a nothing call (unless it does things to the response headers - I've never really looked at what it does internally).

Comment: Ah thank you. I knew it had to be something since he said it was throwing an error later on. I've never had RedirectToAction without the return, and just mentally assumed that it was there. Thanks, I'll update my answer to correct for that.

Comment: Guess I´ve putted it wrong in my code, now nothing happens, I can always click the link without anything happens, the page just refresh and nothing more.

Comment: As I said before, try putting a break point in this method then and see what's happening that does not do what you want it to do. It might be better to remove the `return` from the `default` to after your catch. I did it the way I wrote it because your instructions were unclear. However, this should be more than enough to get you on your way.